# CatalogSearch Layered Navigation on custom category page

Tags: extensions, layered-navigation, catalogsearch

I extended `Mage_CatalogSearch_Helper_Data` into my own class and am using it to retrieve a collection of products that have specific manufacturer part numbers. I then display the matching products on a custom category page.

I want to now add the catalog search layered navigation to my custom category page, so I extended the `Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Layer` and `Mage_CatalogSearch_Block_Layer`classes. I overwrote `Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Layer`'s `getProductCollection` method to get the collection created by my helper file.

How do I now include this block in my custom category template?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to @stackMagento. Your question appears to be too short and difficult to understand. Please update your question by including specified files in the question. We are happy to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work if you're using the 2 columns layout:

```
<reference name="left">
  <block type="catalog_search/catalog_layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Just remember `type` will reference the extended block path/filename.